# Where is the configuration to open a specific web browser in python?

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

This is a Win10 machine.

I have a file on disk called "test.html". When I run this in a terminal window `C:\>test.html` my default browser opens, and that is chrome.

Now I do the same in python

```
C:\> copy con test.py
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('http://www.python.org')
^Z
    1 file(s) copied.
C:\>python test.py
```

and Chrome, the default browser opens

But when I take an HTML response from an API call, and do the same `webbrowser.open(...)` then Internet Explorer opens. Not Edge, not Chrome, but Internet explorer.

How? It's almost as if there is something in the response that tells it "open with IE" except that if do it manually from the command line with `C:\>response.html` it opens chrome too.

Where is this instruction to open Internet Explorer coming from?

Comment: What do you mean "take an HTML response from an API call" ?  Are you passing something that's not a URL to `webborwser.open()` ?

Comment: Yes, I was taking the HTML document, and passing that.

Comment: `webbrowser.open()` is only documented as supporting opening a URL, and best effort of opening a file, it does not support opening a HTML string directly, I'd expect nearly any behavior when using it incorrectly.

Comment: Rightyo, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2):

It *should* use your default browser. Otherwise, [it falls back to IE](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/webbrowser.py#L541-L547)

It appears to use [`os.startfile()` to detect file associations](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/webbrowser.py#L609-L613), so running `os.startfile('response.html')` apparently throws a OSError for you, and you have no other browser installed in the list. Surprisingly, `"chrome"` nor `"edge"` is listed there.

Related - https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/11327

Another option you could try is to use something like `webbrowser.open("file://c/response.html")`

Comment: Its interesting that "chrome" isnt listed in the browsers to fall back on in win, though I do see others like "firefox" listed apparently.

Comment: Falls back to IE... Yes, it certainly looks like that. But I do have three other browsers installed, and Chrome is my default. I'm guessing there is a an environmental con figuration bug somewhere in my OS

Comment: @Maxcot Well, you can see the source code which browsers it tries to find.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `webbrowser.get()`.

For example, opening a new tab in Google Chrome:

```
webbrowser.get(using='google-chrome').open_new_tab('https://google.com')
```

But it is not always possible to get by with .get () alone, and in this case the .register () function comes to the rescue, for example:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.register('Chrome', None, webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser('C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'))
webbrowser.get('Chrome').open_new_tab('google.com')
```

You can also check these links:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html
http://pymotw.com/2/webbrowser/
https://discourse.world/h/2019/10/10/How-to-open-a-link-in-Python.Working-with-WebBrowser-and-solving-a-problem-with-Internet-Explorer

Comment: The question was about opening a static html file. `get("http://...")` seems to work fine